# Tratar um array POST vindo de uma tabela

Tags: php, html, array, tabela-html, array-associativo

Boa noite meus caros.

Estou com uma dificuldade em tratar alguns dados.
Criei uma tabela, onde as `<td>` são alimentadas dinamicamente quando passa por um foreach assim:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tb-despesas">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Conta(s)</th>
           <th>Valor Cobrar</th>
           <th>Valor Real</th>
           <th>Referente</th>
           <th>Consumo</th>
           <th>Medidas</th>
           <th>Obs.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
            foreach($Despesas->getResult() as $Despesa):
            extract($Despesa);
       ?>
       <tr>
           <td name="nm_nome"><?=$nm_nome?></td>
           <td><input name="vl_valor[]" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
           <td><input name="vl_valorreal[]" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
           <td><input name="referente[]" id="dt" class="form-control" type="month"></td>
           <td><input name="consumo[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
           <td><input name="medidas[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
           <td><input name="obs[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
       </tr>
       <?php
          endforeach;
       ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Nessa etapa, devido uma classe que tenho que faz a inserção no banco de dados por array, eu precisava receber isso como:

```
array
   0 =>
     'vl_valor' => '123',
     'vl_valorreal' => '123',
     'referente' => '2018-11'
   1 =>
     'vl_valor' => '456',
     'vl_valorreal' => '456',
     'referente' => '2018-11'
```

Porém o que acabo recebendo no meu $_POST é algo diferente pois junta tudo.
Acaba ficando assim:

```
array
  'vl_valor' => 
    array (size=74)
      0 => string '1234' (length=4)
      1 => string '2345' (length=4)
  'vl_valorreal' => 
    array (size=74)
      0 => string '1234' (length=4)
      1 => string '2345' (length=4)
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz, de como tratar isso? Queria fazer algum foreach pra cada linha que encontrasse pudesse fazer uma inserção no banco de dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução para isso é reorganizar o array para a forma que você já está esperando, veja como ficaria:

```
function reorganizaArray($arr) {
    $arrOrganizado = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr['vl_valor']); $i++) {
        $temp = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $temp[$key] = $value[$i];
        }
        $arrOrganizado[] = $temp;
    }
    return $arrOrganizado;
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KLGk46).

Comment: Imaginei que precisaria fazer algo assim, o problema é que não está entrando na minha cabeça qual a lógica correta. Com o exemplo que você me passou, seria com o array já em um modelo que eu conseguiria usar. Porém o meu var_dump atual vem assim:
https://ideone.com/82BhZQ

Comment: @Rafael, eu usei como exemplo exatamente o mesmo array que você colocou na pergunta, tenta usar essa função ai.

Comment: Sim, eu tentei, mas o array que eu recebo é diferente do usado no exemplo. Em seu exemplo o array está no formato do primeiro resultado que mostrei na pergunta, o que eu recebo é o segundo array da minha pergunta. Esta é a dificuldade.

Comment: Se você tiver certeza que os valores sempre virão neste formato, você pode utilizar esta solução: https://ideone.com/qijVay

Comment: Ah agora sim. Até tentei fazer a contagem pelos resultados mas não acertei. Sempre vou receber assim pois o primeiro parametro sempre será preenchido. 
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.